# video with a transparent background

Tags: rendering

[image]I exported simple video with settings as you see in this pictures. I made three circles filled them up and made them with material surface emission. Three different colours. I set rendering options For Film Transparent And colour management View Transform as standard.  On Output properties for Output, File format as FFmpeg Video for Colour RGBA. on the Encoding section for Container I placed Qucktime and In Video QT rle/ QT Animat.... All this is from Youtube tutorials I hope my pictures help to understand more clearly. I tryed For encoding Different formats as WebM and WEBM/VP9 but same result...
So video is 50 frames  and doesn't take long to render.

[image]

In the second picture You can see I'm trying out the rendered video placing it on the top of the background picture with the car. On the composition section For my rendered video I put screen option as they told in youtube video. I try other options but it didn't worked. As you see on the second picture green circle is barely visible same happens with any other colour but black is not visible at all. Only colour what is clearly visible is white. How do I fix that all I need is the background to be transparent but not the objects I place on the scene so How do I Fix That?

please if you understand what is my issue let me know I can't add second picture for some technical issues... my appologies for my English.. thnaks

Comment: Hello and welcome, please edit your question, there is only one image and some descriptions were hidden (fix it)

Comment: The "Screen" option is more like adding the layer with the objects to the underlying background. Since black has RGB values of 0, adding 0 doesn't change the background so it seems to be invisible. The RGB values of a dark green circle are just adding slightly to the background so it's just faintly visible. The white circle on the other hand has RGB values of 1, so each color channel where you add 1 will at least be 1 or bigger than 1. Since 1 is the highest values allowed for standard RGB images, everything shows white where the white circle is. You should use _Alpha Over_ node.

Comment: Hi. I apply the second image so top one is the second image and bottom one is the first image. 
So how do I apply Alpha Over node. Do I apply it For each Object I want to be visible?

Comment: I can't find alpha editor in any of the editors?

Comment: I mean. I can't find Alpha Over node in any of the editors?

Comment: I thought you were laying it over in _Screen_ mode in the _Compositor_ because there was no first screenshot and you said something about "composition section"... in the _Compositor_ there you have an _Alpha Over_ node. In the _Video Sequence Editor_ you should simply use the _Blend_ option "Alpha Over" instead of "Screen".

Comment: Yes. I try Alpha over for Blend option and background turns black and I can't see the picture behind it.  What could be the cause, maybe I'm doing something wrong? Thanks for reply

Comment: Does the movie you're laying over the image support transparency? If not, then the areas which should be transparent are shown black - and block the image underneath. The _Screen_ mode doesn't do this because the black doesn't add anything to the underlying layer. But as you already experienced it doesn't show the foreground as you want it. You either should make sure that the video format really can display transparency (most formats cannot) and is set up correctly to do so, or even better: don't render your animation as a video, render it as a PNG image sequence with transparency.

Comment: You can se the way I set it up its from youtube tutorials. I'm not really sure abaut PNG but will try

Comment: You see I'm not familiar with how Quicktime handles Alpha transparency since I'm never using it. If you play the video in any given player, does it show transparency or is the background black there as well? I can't see that from the screenshots.